# What does G_DEFINE_TYPE mean in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

Im trying to understand the fundamentals of this basic GTK program. I can't figure out how `G_DEFINE_TYPE` works. It looks similar to a function declaration like those in C`

```
struct _LearnWindow
{
  GtkApplicationWindow  parent_instance;

  /* Template widgets */
  GtkHeaderBar        *header_bar;
  GtkLabel            *label;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (LearnWindow, learn_window, GTK_TYPE_APPLICATION_WINDOW)

static void
learn_window_class_init (LearnWindowClass *klass)
{
  GtkWidgetClass *widget_class = GTK_WIDGET_CLASS (klass);

  gtk_widget_class_set_template_from_resource (widget_class, "/org/gnome/Learn/learn-window.ui");
  gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child (widget_class, LearnWindow, header_bar);
  gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child (widget_class, LearnWindow, label);
}

static void
learn_window_init (LearnWindow *self)
{
  gtk_widget_init_template (GTK_WIDGET (self));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.DEFINE_TYPE.html)

```
#define G_DEFINE_TYPE(TN, t_n, T_P) G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED (TN, t_n, T_P, 0, {})
```

> A convenience macro for type implementations, which declares a class initialization function, an instance initialization function (see GTypeInfo for information about these) and a static variable named t_n_parent_class pointing to the parent class. Furthermore, it defines a *_get_type() function.

Comment: Can someone explain what type implementations are

Comment: A type is a [custom GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject.html) and the implementation is... well, its implementation.